# Creating a up reverse node reference list of a node in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

What we are trying to do in Drupal 7: create a block that can be attached to a node view or taxonomy term view. In this block, a user can add links. These links can point to contacts, documents, links to other websites or taxonomy terms.
In the back-end, a user can select a contact, document or link. The user then gets a list of all nodes where this link is used. If the link is changed, it is updated in all the nodes where it is used.

In other words, a node reference that works in both directions, for multiple nodes. Any ideas are mightily appreciated :)

Comment: Rather than "reverse", try searching for "backlinks". I don't believe that there's any existing solution that handles these links like you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried to use Corresponding node references module? http://drupal.org/project/cnr

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
http://drupal.org/project/content_dependency

It works for both node reference & entity reference modules automatically.